# What to use instead of the "lock" statement when the code is running on multiple machines?

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronization, cluster-computing, server-farm

The [`lock` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. However, it won't work if the workload is spread across a farm of servers (e.g. a few IIS servers + a load balancer).

Does .NET support such a scenario?
Is there any class that can be used to control the execution of a critical code section by threads running on multiple machines?

If not, is there any standard method of handling such problems?

<sup>This question was inspired by a [discussion that started here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8148771/95) but is not limited to SharePoint or ASP.NET.</sup>

Comment: +1: Interesting question. I just googled "distributed lock manager" and learned a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to a centralized SQL Server instance, you can use it to act as a distributed lock coordinator and manage the application locks using the [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) and [sp_releaseapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx) stored procedures.

[Application Locks (or Mutexes) in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 4):

The `lock` statement is only useful for sharing resources within a process.

The `Mutex` and `EventWaitHandle` classes are useful for sharing resources among multiple processes on a single machine when using names that start with `"Global\"`.

Beyond that, you will have to implement something outside .NET, like using `sp_getapplock`/`sp_releaseapplock` on a shared SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Since a network of machines in a standard scenario does not operate on shared memory, they have no global view of a single variable that can be used for synchronization. Therefore, you have to implement locks by means of message passing.

If you want to lock shared resources, you can have a central "master" regulate access to that resource.

Edit: If what you need is not sharing resources (e.g. a barrier), you can use for example MSMQ to pass messages between the machines. Probably sockets are too low level.

Comment: Are there any standard implementations I can use or do I need to create one myself?

Comment: Well it depends what exactly is inside the code that you are trying to protect. If it's a database access, then you can regulate access at the level of the db server.

Comment: Mutexes can be used for cross-process locking.

Comment: @chibacity: Mutexes between different machines? Maybe you should read the question before downvoting.

Comment: My apologies I did not read the question correctly. If you make a small edit to your answer, I will undo my down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to implement an inter-machine threading control with ASP.NET right now. But this can be implemented via a higher level application architecture. Basically, you would have to implement it yourself using your own business logic.

Architecturally, you should introduce a ILockable interface in your solution, and have classes that need to cease operation at some condition to implement it. Then use a set of Gateways to mutually manage those locks.

Comment: Mutexes can be used for cross-process locking.

Comment: @chibacity - Even if the processes are executed on a different operating systems?

Comment: My apologies I did not read the question correctly. If you make a small edit to your answer, I will undo my down-vote.

Comment: @chibacity - it's ok, but me initially mentioning "inter-machine" already constrains that the answer is only true in cross-system scenarios. I don't know how more specific about it can I be.

Comment: I cannot undo my down-vote unless you make an edit to your answer. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in .Net that can natively support cross-machine locking.

The standard method is to move the responsibility for such things to a single place, possibly a web service (not load balanced!), so it can still be called from multiple locations. Or alternatively, defining a single resource, that's accessible by all (eg database) and using this as the single resource to acquire (eg write key in locks table, if key exists lock cannot be acquired until row removed)

Comment: You can use a Mutex for locking across AppDomains.

Comment: @chibacity Thanks, I was not aware that instances of Mutex could be passed across AppDomain boundaries. Answer now updated.